# Couldn't store 2 arrays in php session

Tags: php, session

I have php.ini `memory_limit =1000M`

I have to store notification in session to make alert, at same time user details also have to be stored in session

notification data is stored in

```
$notification['content'] = account_update_failed;
$notification['class'] =  'danger';
$_SESSION['notification'] = $notification;
```

session data is stored in

```
if($login_query->num_rows > 0){
    $login_row = $login_query->fetch_assoc(); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $login_row;
}
```

On both of this session array, only one is transfered when redirecting to another page..

another one is automatically destroyed as well as not shown in next page loadings.. 
  How i set session arrays at this kind of situation?

Notification alert method

```
  // Notifications Creation 
    if($_SESSION['notification']){
     $content = $_SESSION['notification']['content'];
     $delay = ($_SESSION['notification']['duration'] !=true)?2000:$_SESSION['notification']['duration'];
     $class = ($_SESSION['notification']['class'] !=true)?"info":$_SESSION['notification']['class'];

 echo "<script>$(document).ready(function (){
            $.bootstrapGrowl('".$content."',{
                type: '".$class."',
                delay: ".$delay.",
                offset:{from:'top',amount:250},
                align:'center'
      });   });</script>"; 
}

   unset($_SESSION['notification']);
```

Comment: Did you start the session? `session_start()` at the top of each page

Comment: You have some fault in your code.Because it's not happen that two session array destroy each-other itself/Or not passed to other pages. can you be more clear  by providing complete code like how's you setting and sending and how's you are retrieving those SESSION variables.And did you have `session_start();` on top of both pages?

Comment: see my updated question @Alive to Die ..I have put `session_start()` at the header section.. this notification is working on login,logout page..because at that time i don't have user session array..when i try to use both `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['notification']` ,its not working

Comment: You explicitly remove the notification session when you do `unset($_SESSION['notification']);` - is that your intention? And are you 100% sure the session is started in *every* document you are trying to use it?

Comment: Oops.. I found it guys...i didn't put `exit` after page redirect..so that remaining codes executed and unset the `$_SESSION['notification']`...Thank You buddy.